# How to access pre-rendered ID of parents in a directive, to be used in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use the ID of the parent of a directive 'slider' in order to iterate through an array ranges[ID], but that ID is rendered before the directive.

These are the parents:

```
     <divtest id="1" class="divtest hidden"></divtest>
     <divtest id="2" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="3" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="4" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="5" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="6" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="7" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="8" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="9" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="10" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="11" class="divtest"></divtest>
     <divtest id="12" class="divtest hidden"></divtest>

 </ul>
```

The template of divtest is

```
     <li><div><slider></slider></div></li>
```

the template of slider is

```
     <li class="slider-list" ng-repeat="character in range">{{character}}</li>
```

and here is the code of the slider directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('keyboardPrototypeApp')
 .directive('slider', function () {
   return {
     templateUrl: '../../views/slider.html',
     replace: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope){

  },
  link: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      if(element.parents('li.divtest')[0]){

          var index = parseInt((element.parents('li.divtest')[0].id));

          var ranges = {2:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ],
              3:[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 ],
              4:[20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 ],
              5:[30,3,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39 ],
              6:[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49 ],
              7:[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59 ],
              8:[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69 ],
              9:[70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79 ],
              10:[80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89 ],
              11:[90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99 ]
          };
          scope.range = ranges[index];
      }
  }
 };
});
```

How can I access the ID of the parent in that slider directive to use it as the index for the ranges array?

Comment: I think you just need htmlElement.getAttribute("id"), it seems a bit strange to me to use the id for this though, I would probably favor using some custom attribute data-listId="1" or something like that

Comment: I had created a custom attribute called index, but I couldn't access it through the directive, like I could access the ID.

And I can access the ID, but when I use it as the index for the range in ng-repeat, it doesn't see it.

Comment: ah for that part I think you need to toString the index, otherwise it's looking for a numeric index like an array, really you're accessing the property name that has an array stored there... or on second look just don't parseInt it